# LDAP query construction to configure Discovering Products in KMS

Tags: ldap

**Hi.
I would like to discover all servers in specified OU in domain via Volume Activation Management Tool.**

Could you guys help me with it?
regards

this is what I have tried, but does not work
(&(objectclass=computer)(OU=xxx,OU=xxxx,DC=domain,DC=suf,DC=fx"))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions.